# Background image is not showing in the hero section

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to practice by doing some projects..
I'm trying to build a landing page, with the hero section containing  a background but for some reason it's not showing.

here's the html :

```
<body>
  <section id="hero">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Blouza Technologies</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Demos</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
          <h1 class="hero-title">Make your website design a reality.</h1>
          <h3 class="hero-desc">Blouza Technologies is your optimal solution to make your website idea come to life. With a passionate, smart and intelligent team the results will always beat your imagination.</h3>
          <button class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg hero-btn" type="button" name="button">Get Started</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
          <img class="hero-image" src="images/hero-img.png" alt="Hero Image">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </section>
```

CSS :

```
#hero {
  background-image: url("images/bg-img.png");
  background-color: black;
  text-align: left;
}

#hero .container-fluid {
  padding : 3% 15% 7%;
}
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: Seems to work just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/yLaqvd28/

Comment: Already found the problem ! thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, turns out "images/bg-img.png" was looking for the folder "images" inside the "css" folder, so I fixed it by changing it from

```
background-image: url("images/bg-img.png");
```

to :

```
background-image: url("../images/bg-img.png");
```

so now it's looking  for the "images" folder in the project's folder instead of CSS folder.
Thank you for the assist !